If I have two 401k accounts is it smart to roll one over into an Roth IRA every year?
Currently working 2 jobs and have 2 401k accounts.
I am not hitting the tax limit for both but my question is what should I do?
I have my 401k from Company A, which has a 6% match and I am paying 6%
Company B has a $0.75/$1 match up to 4%.
The growth on Company B 401k is not great, but if I understand how 401k's work it will get better as time goes on.
So lets say at the end of the Year I have $6500 in my 401k account from Company B, I talked with an advisor who said I can roll over any 401k to my Roth IRA without a tax penalty. My Roth IRA has been sitting really doing nothing for about 6 years.
Should I take $6000 from my 401k from Company B and put it into my Roth IRA every year? I plan on investing in low risk dividend stocks.
Understanding that will leave me with $500 left over, but I think the max I can put into an Roth IRA every year is $6000
The following year, same time leaving $1000, so on.

Littleadv is correct that a rollover from a Traditional 401(k) to a Roth IRA is treated as income and should be a primary consideration (and is not subject to the constribution limits), but there are some other misconceptions that I think should be addressed.
The primary financial reason to convert from a Traditional 401(k) (or IRA) to a Roth is if you believe your tax bracket now is lower than it will be in the future. Meaning, you take the tax hit now at a lower rate rather than taking the tax hit in retirement. So it's not clear why you want to roll to a Roth at this point.

The growth on Company B 401k is not great, but if I understand how 401k's work it will get better as time goes on.

I'm not sure what you are referring to - there's no "magic" to 401(k)s that make returns "better as time goes on". It's what your 401(k) is invested in that determined the returns - so perhaps your investment choices are limited at Company B and they aren't performing as well, but time will not change that.

I plan on investing in low risk dividend stocks.

There should be no emphasis on dividends in an IRA (Roth or Traditional). Dividends are not income since the value of the stock drops by a similar amount (it is equivalent to cashing out a small portion of your investments without actually selling anything), and there's no tax difference when they are paid within either retirement account type. In a Traditional IRA, any qualified distribution is treated as ordinary income; in a Roth IRA, any qualified distribution is tax-free. So there's no special tax benefit for dividends and they have no impact on overall wealth.
It doesn't hurt to invest in dividend stocks, just be aware that there's no tax benefit like there often is in non-retirement investment accounts.


I am not hitting the tax limit for both but my question is what should I do?

The tax limit is for both combined, not for each separately. Not sure from your phrasing what you think the limit is. For 2024, the limit on your total 401k contributions (to all the plans) is $23000.

I talked with an advisor who said I can roll over any 401k to my Roth IRA without a tax penalty.

There's no penalty on rollovers, but if you're rolling over from Traditional 401k to Roth IRA - the rolled over amount is added to your taxable income. You'll need to pay tax on that rollover.

the max I can put into an Roth IRA every year is $6000

This is for contributions, there's no limit on rollovers. The Roth IRA contribution limits depend on your income, but if you earn above the income maximum, you can still contribute to the traditional IRA and then convert to Roth (see "backdoor Roth IRA"). Note that if you have an existing traditional IRA balance, it complicates the backdoor conversion a bit.

Also, worth mentioning, 401k plans may not allow outgoing rollovers before separation. You should check with your plan.

I think that last sentence "401k plans may not allow outgoing rollovers before separation. You should check with your plan." needs more prominence than sounding just like an afterthought "Oh, by the way". I believe that the vast majority of 401(k) plans prohibit in-service rollovers.
